# Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\wooOrders.log' is denied

Tags: c#, iis

I have a WebApp running under the default AppPool in IIS.

In my webApi project, I have an [HttpGet] method and an [HttpPost] method.

I have a custom bit of code that basically tries to create a text file in the app location write to it and close.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

Reporting.PrepareChannel("log", path + ".log");

Reporting.Report("WooOrders", "order created from webhook - Woo order no: ");
Reporting.Shutdown();
```

placing the above in my [HttpGet] method all works fine, but in my [HttpPost] method It drops onto my catch block and returns the above error?

I'm at a loss as to why this is?

In my [HttpGet] method it creates the file in the physical location that I expect it to be in which is on our 'D' drive.

Here's the full code for both methods. Although I've deployed to our live environment they are not being used yet. I've cut the methods down to literally just create the file write to it and close. I've commented out all other processing for the moment.

```
 [Route("api/woo/createOrder")]
        [HttpPost]
        public string CreateOrder([FromBody] Models.Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                Reporting.PrepareChannel("log", path + ".log");

                Reporting.Report("WooOrders", "order created from webhook - Woo order no: ");
                Reporting.Shutdown();
                return "all good";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Reporting.Shutdown();
                return ex.Message;
            }
}



[Route("api/woo/getOrder/{id}")]
            [HttpGet]
            public string OrderGet([FromUri] string Id)
            {
                try
                {
                    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    
                    Reporting.PrepareChannel("log", path + ".log");
    
                    Reporting.Report("WooOrders", "Get Order ");
                    Reporting.Shutdown();
                    return "all good";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Reporting.Shutdown();
                    return ex.Message;
                }
    }
```

Comment: Specify an absolute path. Usually, I do this in "Web.config" (.NET Framework) or in "appsettings.json" (.NET Core).

Comment: I tried that so I set string path = "d:\\firstdirectory\\logdirectory" and it still gave the same error

Comment: Then I would follow the steps in "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: Works fine in Debug, it's when deployed. Hence my code directly in both functions, and using postman to try and figure out the issue. If it was failing with permissions for both methods I'd have more of an idea, but 1 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Whatever library `Reporting.PrepareChannel` is from; maybe it behaves differently than you expect it to do?

Comment: @bilpor Make sure the file isn't locked. Do you have multiple threads trying to write to this file at one time? Since you haven't shared some of your code, the part which writes to the file, it's hard to say what the problem is, but I don't think it has anything to do with what type of Http Request is taking place.

Comment: Does the IIS worker process user (probably `IIS AppPool\websitenamehere`) have permission to write to the path given?

Comment: @RyanWilson I've updated my question with the 2 methods stripped right back. So I run the HttpGet via postman to my live server after deployment and the file gets created and written. I then delete the file to ensure no pollution. I then run the post method from postman and I get the error.

Comment: @CaiusJard On the basis that it writes when the HttpGet method is called I'd have thought so, otherwise I'd expect the same issue with that.

Comment: @bilpor Are you calling the `post` method after creating the file in the `get` method? Or does the file not exist when calling the `post` method as you would the `get` method. What does `PrepareChannel()` do, and what are it's accepted parameters?

Comment: @RyanWilson when I call the `post` method I ensure the log file does not exist. The same go's for the `get` method, before I call that I ensure the file does not exist. So clean slate every time.

Comment: According to the stack trace, what exact line of code was executing when the exception was thrown?

Comment: @JohnWu it is at the point that it is trying to write. The file seems to get created, but is empty. So the error occurs in `Reporting.Report` this uses a streamwriter to write to the file that has been opened. The pertinent lines in there is that it uses `WriteLine` followed by `Flush`

Comment: @bilpor I understand, but I am asking about the *specific* line of code as shown in the stack trace. There can be only one. Is `Reporting` a class that you own or is it third party?

Comment: @JohnWu, yes Reporting is my own class. THere is no stack trace, I'm calling from postman to a WebApi on a deployed environment, so there's no code to step. This is why I'm using my own reporting class, but it fails before it get's a chance to write anything, as mentioned though the same code as you can see above works calling the 'HttpGet' method

Comment: If there is an exception, there's a stack trace. If you can't step debug through it, you can also log it. What I'm asking for is not unusual. If you don't know where the exception is coming from you are just guessing. If you are writing to a file on `D:` but the error says `C:` it's quite possible the error has nothing to do with your write operation.

Comment: @JohnWu yes, that's why I've done what I did in the code above. I stripped it back to the bare minimum. Trouble is as you can see, it's not logging because it's not getting that far.